# Running sql SubQueries in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

hello everyone i am working on mycollege project and trying to make a user login application in asp.dot net.
I have two tables in my database one is customer full detail and other is customer login detail
What I want to do to count the row in first query and if login_id and password matches then it executes the other query to retrive and displays the customer first name, on the redirectedd page 
below is what i have done any other type of  method is also welcomed 
here is my code

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    connection.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(*) from customer_login where login_id = @a and pass_login=@b",connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", Login1.UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", Login1.Password);
    string user_name;
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (i == 1)
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select f_name from customer where id = (select cust_id from customer_login where login_id = @a)", connection);//This query successfully runs in mssms but it gives error in aspx
      // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c",new SqlCommand ("select cust_id from customer_login where login_id = @a"));
      //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", Login1.UserName);

        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        sdr.Read();
        user_name = sdr["f_name"].ToString();
        sdr.Close();
        if (Session["productID"] != null)
        {
            Session["user"] = user_name.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Detail/cart.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }

}
```

the problem is it gives following error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@a". "
 thanku

Comment: cmd refers to a new command for the next query. So You need to add the parameter @a again. Alternatively you can use cmd.CommandText property to set a new query instead of making new SqlCommand. in This way the older parameters will come in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have not assigned value to `@a`

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select f_name from customer where id = (select cust_id from customer_login where login_id = @a)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

please

```
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", Login1.UserName);
```

uncomments this line to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", Login1.UserName);
```

then check again